# What happens when an object is assigned to another object

Tags: java, object

```
public class DrumKitTestDrive {
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Echo e1 = new Echo();
    Echo e2 = new Echo();
//      **e2 = e1;**

    int x=0;
    while( x < 4 ){
        e1.hello();
        e1.count = e1.count + 1;
        if(x==3){
            e2.count = e2.count + 1;
        }
        if(x>0){
            e2.count = e2.count + e1.count;
        }
        x = x + 1;
    }
    System.out.print(e2.count);
    }
}

class Echo {
    int  count = 0;

    void hello(){
        System.out.println("Hellooooo....");
    }
}
```

The output of this code will be:

```
Hellooooo....
Hellooooo....
Hellooooo....
Hellooooo....
10
```

But if I remove the comments from `// e2= e1;` when I run the code the system will print *24* instead of *10*. I don't understand why is it so?

What I understand is the system will just copy the values of `e1` instance into `e2` instance. And if the system will do so, the result shall remain the same because both objects are of the same class.

Answer (score 23):

> What I understand is the system will just copy the values of e1 instance into e2 instance.

No, when you do `e2 = e1` you're copying object *references* - you're not making a copy of the object - and so the variables `e1` and `e2` will both point to the *same object*.

And so when you do your increments, they're all incrementing the same count field.

It's only without the assignment `e2 = e1` that the increments are happening on two different instances.

Comment: Thank you! Does that mean that the object copying the reference of the other object would be able to change it's values and call it's methods etc? So, we will not have a copy of the object?

Comment: Hey @Avv. If I understand your question: yes. After the _assignment_ `e2 = e1` now you just have 2 different names for the _same thing_. So calling a method on `e2` or `e1` will have the same effect: both would be manipulating the same underlying object.

Answer (score 7):

This is one of the basic principles of Java. Each variable, is just a handle to some object. Executing

```
e1=e2
```

doesn't copy the values of the objects, it points both `handles` to the second object that was created. The first `Echo` object that you instantiated is now not referenced at all, and will be garbage collected the next time gc runs.

Answer (score 5):

Assigning one object to another just assigns the object reference (a pointer more or less). It does NOT copy member variables etc.

You need to read about [cloning](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&sugexp=les;&gs_nf=1&tok=fPNNP7J3M1z4x17yNHBNmA&cp=8&gs_id=f&xhr=t&q=java%20clone&pf=p&safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=java%20clo&gs_l=&pbx=1&qscrl=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=8171fb77536c4765&biw=1680&bih=989&ion=1). From the first paragraph of the wiki for Java `clone()`:

> In Java, objects are manipulated through reference variables, and
>   there is no operator for copying an object—the assignment operator
>   duplicates the reference, not the object. The clone() method provides
>   this missing functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating constructor for method Echo, with another object as parameter.
And assign values of parameter object to this object.
i.e.
'''

```
Echo(Echo echo) {
  this.count = echo.count;
}
```

'''

And then create the node e2 as:

```
Echo e2 = new Echo(e1);
```