# Java object assignment behaviour not consistent?

Tags: java, object, assign

According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12020435/562222 , assigning an object to another is just copying references, but let's see this code snippet:

```
public class TestJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        {
            Integer x;
            Integer y = 223432;
            x = y;
            x += 23;
            System.out.println(x);
            System.out.println(y);
        }
        {
            Integer[] x;
            Integer[] y = {1,2, 3, 4, 5};
            x = y;
            x[0] += 10;
            printArray(x);
            printArray(y);
        }
    }

    public static <T> void printArray(T[] inputArray) {
        for(T element : inputArray) {
            System.out.printf("%s ", element);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Running it gives:

```
223455
223432
11 2 3 4 5 
11 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Note that `x += 23;` is the same as `x = x + 23;`, therefore it is an assignment of the reference `x`.

Comment: @Radiodef - Actually, it's the same as `x = Integer.valueOf(x.intValue() + 23);`

Comment: @TedHopp You're correct it expands fully to that but my point is it is a reference assignment whether you know that unboxing and boxing happens or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior is consistent. This line:

```
x += 23;
```

actually assigns a different `Integer` object to `x`; it does not modify the value represented by `x` before that statement (which was, in fact, identical to object `y`). Behind the scenes, the compiler is unboxing `x` and then boxing the result of adding 23, as if the code were written:

```
x = Integer.valueOf(x.intValue() + 23);
```

You can see exactly this if you examine the bytecode that is generated when you compile (just run `javap -c TestJava` after compiling).

What's going on in the second piece is that this line:

```
x[0] += 10;
```

also assigns a new object to `x[0]`. But since `x` and `y` refer to the same array, this also changes `y[0]` to be the new object.

Answer (score 1):

`Integer` is immutable, so you cannot modify its state once created. When you do this:

```
Integer x;
Integer y = 223432;
x = y;
x += 23;
```

The line `x += 23` is assigning a new `Integer` value to `x` variable.

Arrays, on the other hand, are mutable, so when you change the state of the array e.g. changing one of the elements in the array, the other is *affected* as well.

Comment: -0.5.  I find this answer rather misleading.  The difference in behaviour isn't to do with whether an `Integer` or an array is mutable or immutable - it's due to the fact that the assignment in the first block assigns something to `x` and the assignment in the second block does not.  The immutability of `Integer` objects is a complete red herring.

Comment: @DavidWallace since `Integer` is immutable, you do not change its state, but always create a new instance and assign it. That's why it comes into relevance and why doing `x += 23` creates a new instance rather than modifying the current state of the variable.

Comment: But you could do the same kind of thing with a mutable class and see the same effect.

Comment: @DavidWallace if you do `x = new Thatclass(...)` which may break OP's intention.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this  `x += 23;`, you actually create another object, and you made x point on this new object. Therefore, x and y are 2 different objects.